# MongoDb Laravel where clause

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5, eloquent, where-clause, database

In MongoDb i have documents with a field named "common_id". I just want to fetch all documents of a particular common_id.

This is how the common_id field looks like.

```
"common_id" : ObjectId("5911af8209ed4456d069b1d1"),
```

I have tried this,

```
$bestAmongAffiliates = MasterAffiliateProductMappingMongo::where('common_id', '=', 'true')
->get();
```

this,

```
$bestAmongAffiliates = MasterAffiliateProductMappingMongo::where('common_id', '=', 'ObjectId("5911af8209ed4456d069b1d1")')
->get();
```

and this,

```
MasterAffiliateProductMappingMongo::where('common_id', '=', ObjectId("5911af8209ed4456d069b1d1"))
    ->get();
```

also tried this,

```
$bestAmongAffiliates = MasterAffiliateProductMappingMongo::where('common_id', new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID('5911af8209ed4456d069b1d1'));
```

I think the problem is that - **ObjectId("5911af8209ed4456d069b1d1")** is not a string thats why the above codes are not working. Anyway am not sure.
But nothing works. How can i do this.

Comment: `MasterAffiliateProductMappingMongo::where('common_id', ObjectId("5911af8209ed4456d069b1d1"))` surely. And I presume you are actually pulling in `ObjectId` from [MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-objectid.php) as you should.

Comment: Dude, that's exactly why I gave you the link to the BSON library function you **NEED** to be importing.

Comment: @NeilLunn ohh....cool. :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
::where('common_id', '5911af8209ed4456d069b1d1')->get()
```

should work if you are using Jenssegers Laravel MongoDB.

Checks if it `string` and string is `ctype_xdigit` then converts as object in the query builder